# How to get the Telerik RadGrid footer row value?

Tags: c#-4.0, telerik, radgrid

Using C#, how do I get values from a textbox which is in a RadGrid Footer?

I am getting an error in the following code. How do I solve it?

```
TextBox texte=(TextBox)RadGrid1.FooterRow.FindControl("textempno");
```

Comment: in which event are you trying to get this value/

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
if (e.Item is GridFooterItem)
{
    TextBox texte = (TextBox)RadGrid1.FooterRow.FindControl("textempno");
}
```

Also, you can do it like this:

```
GridFooterItem footerItem = (GridFooterItem)RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Footer)[0];
TextBox texte=(TextBox)footerItem.FindControl("textboxid");//accessing Button inside FooterTemplate
```

I have give the index [0] while getting the grid footer item as the text box is the one and only item in my grid footer. If you have multiple footer items, you can give the index of the item you want to find.

Comment: try to find it in footer items